# Is it possible to make a function in Swift that can be linked with and called from C code?

Tags: c, swift

I have a quantity of code written in Swift (on macOS) which I wish to make available to other code written in C. Specifically, I want to create some glue code  in Swift, which exports a number of functions with C calling conventions and unmangled names, and calls the relevant Swift code.

Is it possible to create a Swift file which, contains a function named, let's say, `foo`, which would look something like:

```
func foo() → () {
    print("This is in Swift");
    /// call other Swift code here
}
```

which when compiled with `swiftc` to a `.o` file, can be linked with a C file containing something like:

```
extern void foo();

...

void bar() {
   ...
   printf("This is in C\n");
   foo();
   ...
}
```

?

By default, Swift function names are mangled with type data, and while there is a `@convention(c)` attribute in Swift, it does not appear like it can be used for function declarations, but merely callbacks passed to C code within Swift. Is there a way to allow Swift code to be linked with and called from C?

Answer (score 0):

This is what `@_cdecl` is supposed to allow you to do. It works well most of the time but can be tricky to get right. You apply it to a top level function and all the parameter and return types need to have to be visible to both C and Swift.

So in this case you can add it to foo like this:

```swift
@_cdecl("foo")
func foo() ...
```

This will then provide both the Swift and C names for `foo()` in your symbols. The only other tricky part is getting the linking and run time. You will likely want to start your executable in Swift so the runtime is there but it is possible to start it in C. That said, I only did it once as an experiment and don't remember all the flags I had to pass to get things working when starting in C land.